# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Java.langClassNotFoundExeption

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm having a problem. When launching my code the console gives me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.Test.testApp, PID: 28325
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Test.testApp/com.Test.testApp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.Test.testApp.HomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Test.testApp-nouq7sbVCrcRJQxd835Nvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Test.testApp-nouq7sbVCrcRJQxd835Nvw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3978)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.Test.testApp.HomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Test.testApp-nouq7sbVCrcRJQxd835Nvw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Test.testApp-nouq7sbVCrcRJQxd835Nvw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3963)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247)*
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)*
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)*
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)*
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613)*
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)*
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)*
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)*
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)*
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)*
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
```

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Test.testApp">
 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestTest"
        tools:targetApi="31">
            <activity
                android:name=".HomeActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My HomeActivity.kt :

```
package com.Test.testApp
 
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try by adding complete path in your manifest file like android:name="com.Test.testApp.HomeActivity" also avoid upper case characters in package names.

Comment: What things have you tried to do in trying to fix this issue?

Comment: I have try to add complete path but that change nothing